# What is the correct way to subscribe to ReactiveCommand in RxUI 6?

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, reactiveui

I am trying to get a simple skeleton ViewModel set up with ReactiveUI 6 (beta) and keep getting compiler errors (in Xamarin Studio, FWIW).

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using ReactiveUI;

// ...

public IReactiveCommand TryAuthenticateCommand { get; protected set; }

// ...

this.TryAuthenticateCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(
this.WhenAny(
    x => x.Username,
    x => x.Password,
    (username, password) => 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username.Value) && 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password.Value)));
this.TryAuthenticateCommand.Subscribe(x => MessageBus.Current.SendMessage("Yes!"));
```

Error:

```
Error CS0411: The type arguments for method `System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe<T>(this System.IObservable<T>, System.Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is perfect, i think you're just missing a using statement, "using System.Reactive"

**Update:** The reason that this doesn't work is code that's not in the snippet. You declared `TryAuthenticateCommand` as `IReactiveCommand` which doesn't implement `IObservable<T>` (what would `T` be?).

In this case, since you're not providing an async method to go along with it, ReactiveCommand returns you the CommandParameter, which is an `object`. So declare it as `ReactiveCommand<object>` and everything works

Comment: Tried adding `using System.Reactive;` and it made no difference.

Comment: System.Reactive.Linq? I can never remember where that extension method lives

Comment: Yup, I've got them both (see updated question). Any others? :)

Comment: Can you send me a small repro project? paul@paulbetts.org

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So what should the prototypical definition look like?

Comment: RE: "since you are not providing an async method", could you give an example? Want to make sure I understand the correct usage pattern. Thanks!

Comment: You're using it correctly here, but if you *also* wanted to tie this method to some sort of async method (via the "execute" parameter), the "T" would be the result of the async method instead (way more convenient!)